Environment samepage breaks multicols
When making problem sets for a class, I often want to save a little space so I will use multicols for problems that have many parts. I also often want to keep an entire problem, with all of its parts, on the same page, so I use samepage. For some reason, samepage breaks multicols. Is there an obvious reason for this? If there an option for samepage that I'm not seeing that would take care of this?
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{samepage}
    \noindent
    \textbf{6.} A bunch of instructions here on what to do for this problem, where
    you will do it a bunch of times for practice so that you don't fail the class.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*.}]
            \item The first equation.
            \item The second equation.
            \item The third equation.
            \item The fourth equation.
            \item The fifth equation.
            \item The sixth equation.
            \item The seventh equation.
            \item The eighth equation.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{samepage}\par\goodbreak

\end{document}


all the penalties that stop page breaking will just as equally apply to column breaks so multicols has no chance to find any good column breaks. Use  minipage  to completely prevent a page break
